# How many combinations do we have if we choose $5$ balls out of $10$ if there are $2$ each of five different colors?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let's say we have $10$ balls, $2$ red, $2$ blue, $2$ black, $2$ pink and $2$ green. We want to choose $5$ out of $10$. In how many ways this can be done?

Is it right to tell: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ or is there a problem cause we are calculating Pink-Pink-Blue $2$ times for example?

Comment: Are they identical if the colors are same? Please make more clear your question.

Comment: @LionHeart I think yes. With this way we are calculating Pink-Pink-Blue 2 times but actually its the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to differentiate three cases here:

First of all, you have the case where all of these balls have a different colour. This is 1 possible case.

Secondly, you have the case where one colour appears twice and the three remaining balls are all different. There are five different cases for this. You have three free spots left afterwards - since these have to be all different you get 4 choose 3 options here.

Then, thirdly, you have the case where two colours appear twice each. There are 5 choose 2 options here, and every time there are three colours left for the remaining ball.

Adding and multiplying all of this up you obtain the following calculation:

$$1+5*\binom{4}{3} + \binom{5}{2} *3$$

I hope I didn't miss anything. If you don't know what $\binom{n}{k}$ is, look the 'binomial coefficient' up. This operator tells you how many different ways there are, disregarding order, to choose $k$ objects from $n$ available objects.

Comment: Oh yeah- that was as stupid mistake. That case is the case where all balls are different.

Answer (score 1):

This is same as calcualting number of solutions to equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 5$$where $0\leq x_i\leq 2$ for $i \in\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Hint: This can be solved by applying Inclusion Exclusion Principle

Comment: Formatting tip:  Typing `$\le$` produces $\le$.

Comment: Thank you, edited my answer.